# Rspec inconsistent results between 2 tests with same code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I have a model spec that throws an unexpected error (doesn't build the object right). 
When I move the same code into a previous test, it runs smoothly.

Here's the problematic expectation:

```
expect(title.full_title.length).to be <= 140
```

When adding the line to the first test, it passes, while the second test fails:

```
  describe "generates a title" do
    let(:collection) { FactoryBot.create(:collection) }
    let(:items) { FactoryBot.create_list(:item, 10, collection: collection, chosen: true) }
    let(:title) { Title.create_title(collection) }

context "happy path" do
  it "assigns keywords by score" do
    array = []
    items.each do |i|
      array << [i.search.term, i.search.score]
    end
    array.sort! { |a, b| a[1] <=> b[1] }
    split_title = title.full_title.split(', ')
    remaining_chars = 140
    i = 0

    split_title.each do |s|
      if remaining_chars - s.length >= 0
        expect(s).to eq(array[i][0])
        i +=  1
        remaining_chars -= s.length
      end

      expect(title.full_title.length).to be <= 140
    end
  end

  it "does not exceed 140 characters" do
    expect(title.full_title.length).to be <= 140
  end
end
```

Here is the error message, it doesn't create the object:

```
  1) Title generates a title happy path does not exceed 140 characters
     Failure/Error: remaining_chars = 140 - keywords[0].length

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass
```

TIA!

Comment: It seems it is a different line (and even a different spec) that gave the error. RSpec is telling you it's in the context `sad path` and spec `does not repeat keywords` and the problem is with the `keywords[0].length` expression, where keywords[0] is nil.

Comment: As @TiagoFarias mentioned, please post the `context "sad path"` specs.

Comment: Thanks Tiago and @mmichael, I copied the wrong error message. Just edited the question to include the correct error message.

Comment: we can't help answer without seeing the code this is testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a long shot, but let's try if I'm lucky today.

Guess: `Title.full_title` implementation (which you didn't share) depends somehow on the existence of the `Item`'s related to the collection which is used to initialize the `Title` object.

If that assumption is correct, different behavior comes from the lazy nature of `let`.

In the first `it`, you actually call `items` (e.g. `items.each`) so the `let(:items)` is evaluated, the rows in DB are created and `title.full_title` does not return `nil`.

There a few possible many ways to fix it:

1. Improve the implementation of `full_title` to always return string.
2. call `items` before in the second scenario

`it "does not exceed 140 characters" do
      items
      expect(title.full_title.length).to be <= 140
    end`

3. use `let!(:items)` which is evaluated immediately (not lazy)

Comment: you shoulda filled a lottery form ;) you're a genius! I used let! and it solved the problem, thanks a ton! :)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: BTW. lazy nature of `let` it's a quite common pitfall. You may want to keep that fact in mind.

Comment: Definitely keeping this in mind. Thank you so so much again!